# Finding the range for instruction sets

Tags: mips

(ie how far can it go from the current PC)

I am trying to find the range for the instruction sets on mips

How would you find the range for branch instructionsets, j/jal/ and jr instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Branch instructions have a 16 bit signed offset field. This is a word offset, so the destination address range for branch instructions is +/- 128kByte from the current PC.

The `J` and `JAL` instructions have a 26 bit offset. This is a word offset within the current 256MB aligned address region, so the destination address range for `J` and `JAL` instructions is:

- From `(current-PC & 0xfc000000)` to  `(current-PC & 0xfc000000) + 256MB`.

The `JR` and `JALR` instructions jump to an address contained in a register, so they can jump to any address in the 4GByte address space.

Comment: Good detail, I see your previous answer is similar :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/9038718/832776

Comment: Why current-PC is & with 0xfc000000? 256 MB occupy 28 bit, so it should only & with 0xf0000000.