# Target of jump differs in high-order 4 bits from instruction pc 0x400014

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm working on my MIPS assignment and I am getting this error: "Target of jump differs in high-order 4 bits from instruction pc 0x400014". I would like some help on it.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to jump to a address in memory which is outside the current 256MByte region.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030439/mips-range-of-jump-instruction/9038718#9038718).  You would need to post some source code if you need help identifying the problem in your code.