# Jump MIPS 32 bit instruction

Tags: assembly, mips, bit

I'm studying MIPS 32 bit architecture and I don't understand a few things about jump instruction implementation. 
In particular, why for jump implementation we must insert into PC:

1. the upper 4 bits of the current PC+4
2. the 26-bit immediate field of the jump instruction
3. adding 00 as the 2 low order bits

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/9030439/583570

Answer (score 4):

Current PC+4 is because of pipelining: PC was already incremented before the `Jump` instruction starts to execute.

A `Jump` instruction has only room for 26 bits addressing. So 2 limitations that ensue are:

1. The jump has to be within a 28 bits range from current instruction address, hence using upper 4 bits from PC).
2. The jump has to be word-aligned, that is, the destination address has to be a multiple of 4, hence the lower 2 bits set to 00

Comment: More precisely, the jump has to be within the current 256MByte region specified by the PC's most significant 4 bits, (this is not a PC-relative address).

Comment: @markgz 2^28 = 268435456 = 256 MiB. If you're using PC's bits for the address, then it is a PC-relative address. I don't mean *offset* here.