# branch addresses

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm using mips and I would like you to help me understand something about calculating the branch addresses .
fix me if I'm wrong..in a *machine code*..the address is actually number of word +pc+4 which pc+4 considered the next instruction.
but in mips we would see only the number of word in the index of address we need to get to the label?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MIPS range of jump instruction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030439/mips-range-of-jump-instruction)

Answer (score 0):

With the plethora of available toolchains out there that can produce correct/working machine code, just take a few seconds to create an example:

```
00001000 <_ftext>:
    ...
    1008:   10000008    b   102c <one>
    100c:   00000000    nop
    1010:   00000000    nop
    1014:   10000007    b   1034 <two>
    1018:   00000000    nop
    ...
    1024:   10000005    b   103c <three>
    1028:   00000000    nop

0000102c <one>:
    102c:   03e00008    jr  ra
    1030:   00000000    nop

00001034 <two>:
    1034:   03e00008    jr  ra
    1038:   00000000    nop

0000103c <three>:
    103c:   03e00008    jr  ra
    1040:   00000000    nop
```

the branch to one is at address 0x1008 the address of one is 0x102C a difference of 0x24  which is 9 words.  So yes it appears you take the difference from pc+4 to the target.

This is true for the branch to two 0x1034-(0x1014+4) = 0x1C which is 7 words and that is the encoding.

```
00001000 <_ftext>:
    ...

0000100c <one>:
    ...
    1018:   1000fff9    b   1000 <_ftext>
    101c:   00000000    nop
    1020:   1000fffa    b   100c <one>
    1024:   00000000    nop
```

Likewise branching backward  0x100C - (0x1020+4) = 0xFFF...FFE8.  Convert that to words 0xFF...FFFA and that is the encoding.  Same goes for the other branch in this example.

When you have working tools at your disposal and you are not sure whether or not there is an offset, what the encoding is, etc.  Just use the tools that work, no different than just asking someone, other than being easier and quicker.

Comment: if i need to branch backwards i will notice that the adreess in the brach is negative acording to the 2's complement right?

Comment: your program that does the math "simply" does the subtraction as I have described in the text, and then you do the shift right of 2 to convert to words instead of bytes (the two lsbits should be zeros anyway) and then mask off the correct number of bits to fit into the slot in the machine instruction.  use a 32 bit variable basically so you have the two extra bits before shifting.  alternatively you can do the shifting first and add one instead of adding 4...or you can do the add ajustment after the subtraction, it all works the same.

Comment: Yes it is a signed (twos complement) offset that is encoded in the instruction, in units of words/instructions, not in units of bytes.  If you just look at the branch to three above, the encoding shows a 5, but the label three is 6 instructions away.  OR it is 5 instructions from the instruction after the branch and that is basically what you are asking and you are correct (pc+4 which is the instruction after)

Comment: x=destination-(current_address+4);   y=(x>>2)&0xFFFF.  and y is what you encode in the instruction.

Comment: My main point is that if there is already a working toolchain, you can figure it out from that (plus documentation).  If there is not a toolchain then you probably work for/with the design team and you can just ask the chip designer how to compute offset in the instruction.