# Given instruction address and target address, how to tell if this is a branch instruction or jump instruction

Tags: assembly, mips

I am new to the MIPS assembly language, and I get stuck with a question on the text back.

The question given the instruction address and target instruction, and then calculate whether it's a branch instruction or a jump instruction.

Is there any way to calculate this without knowing what the branch instruction is?

Thank you.

For example:

```
instruction address | target address 
     0x0010 0000    |  0x0010 00d0 
     0x1000 0000    |  0x0ffe 0000
```

Comment: You mean conditional branch vs. unconditional branch?  Then no, both kinds of jumps have a target address.  You need the instruction data, not just the instruction address.

Comment: I do not know if this is true in MIPS, but with many processors the range of a branch instruction's displacement (from the next address) is limited, whereas the jump is not. So if the required branch instruction would be out of range, you would use the *opposite* test, to branch past a jump instruction. That jump takes you to where the desired branch could not.

Comment: Jumps in MIPS can target any location in the current 256 MByte region. Branches can target the current PC +/- 128 kBytes. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9038718/583570

Comment: Oh right, I totally forgot about this because modern x86 has rel8 and rel32 encodings for both conditional and unconditional branches.  So you can sometimes tell that it must be a jump, not a conditional branch, but you can never tell that it's definitely not a jump.